# vim and the Makefile

Tags: mactex, vim, makefile

I'm trying to use a Makefile to compile latex files within vim (and update the view of my current pdf file within my favourite viewer). Here is a little example (I'd like to expand that lateron):

```
default: pdf
    open brief.pdf &

pdf: brief.tex
    pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error brief.tex
```

Calling `make` from the console or using `:!make` from within vim works fine. But when I use the build-in `:make` it fails

```
 This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 **
```

and does not stop at that point. I want to make you of the features of the build-in `make` to jump to potential errors directly. I'm using MacOS 10.7.5. (not sure if this has anything to do with this).

Comment: Looks like your makeprg might be set to something else?  what does `:set makeprg?` show?

Comment: makeprg=latex -interaction=nonstopmode $*

Comment: This looks like the plugin latex-suite is installed which sets makeprg. You have to overwrite the setting. see following [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318527/how-to-use-vim-latexsuite-with-a-makefile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment to your question implies the setting of your `makeprg` variable is not set to `make` but to a call to LaTeX. That call to LaTeX is not working. I replicated your error by setting my `makeprg` to what you reported.

If you set your `makeprg` variable to make it should work.

Without knowing more about your VIM setup I can't tell you why your `makeprg` is set that way. Perhaps you have some plugin installed that sets it to this for you.

My environment is OSX 10.8.2 with VIM 7.3 with no TeX/LaTeX plugins installed.

Good luck.